# Validation on has_many relationship Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
```

That has many answers:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :question, :counter_cache => true
   validates :body,
             :presence => true,
             :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 4096}
```

I have a form under a question page, so I can submit answers.

The problem is that after I create a new answer I'm redirected back to the question so, I cannot see any validation errors.

Does anyone knows how to see validation errors from answers on a question page?

This is views/questions/show.html.erb

```
    <%= render :partial => @answers %>

<%= form_for [@question, Answer.new] do |f| %>

    <div class="formline">
    <div class="formlabelcenter"><%= f.label :body, "New Answer" %></div>
    <div class="formfield"> <%= f.text_area :body, :class => "mceEditor" %></div>
    </div>

    <div class="formline">
    <div class="submit">
    <%= f.submit "Add Answer" %></div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to render the question it gets me  to:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/questions/question-name/answers
```

and not to

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/questions/question-name
```

Comment: Are you redirecting after an answer is posted or just rendering the same page? If you're rendering the same page whatever method you use in your view to display errors should be displaying them. Share your view code?

Comment: When I use render it gets me the answers url of the given question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing displaying the errors in your view code that displays the question form, try this (note the change of Answer.new to @answer, so this will display the same model that fails validation in the controller)

```
<%= form_for [@question, @answer || Answer.new] do |f| %>
  <% if @answer && @answer.errors.any? %>
    <div class='errors'>
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@answer.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this user from being saved:
      </h2> 
      <ul>
      <% @answer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>  
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% # your view code here %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy! 
I get undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass as @answer is nil.
I didnt include anything to display errors as it was included on my layout.  
If I just add <%= form_for [@question, @answer || Answer.new] do |f| %> the form does exactly the same thing it gets me to http://0.0.0.0:3000/questions/question-name/answers  Thanks

Comment: You'll need to add `@answer = Answer.new` to the controller method that displays questions, also see update for fix on error display

Comment: I've added the @answer = Answer.new abut when I'm trying to add a new answers it will get me to 0.0.0.0:3000/questions/question-name/answers 
 :(

Comment: what is wrong with that url? do you have your routes setup to nest the answer resources under questions? And what I was pointing out was the second line that I changed.

Comment: You could easily redirect from `index` on AnsersController to the `show` method on QuestionsController

Comment: This is how I'm trying to go to show: render @question (still gets me in that url /question-name/answers)
When I'm using redirect_to @question I can go on the question#show but Im not able to see validation errors.
thanks for your patience Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

When detecting the error in your controller, store its message in `flash[:error]`. Then, in the view, check for the existance of `:error` in the `flash` hash. If it exists, display it as an error message.

Comment: the styling of the flash message is green. I would like to display all errors in the same way that are displayed on my other models for consistency. I've tried that but thanks anyway :)

Comment: The styling is up to you.  You can use the same error displaying used for forms.  Just see how it's set up in the scaffolding.

Comment: Hi Mario,
If I change this, then all my other flash messages on the other models will be displayed as validation errors and I dont want that. Thank you :)